# Python - Getting Start and End Index of a Dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, record

I am looking for help with the following.

Lets say I have a python dataframe as follows:

```
Index A    B    C
1     10   15   20
2     Null 20   11
3     Null 10   Null
4     Null Null Null
5     29   35   40
```

I would like to create a record like given below by iterating through all columns and rows.

```
StartIndex    EndIndex    ColumnName    Comment
2             4           A             Null
4             4           B             Null
3             4           C             Null
```

Here, I may also need to create records based on other conditions other than NULL above.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: can you please display the dataframes in a better way? thanks

Comment: @Joe you are welcome :)

Comment: Thanks Joe and Zipa for the help with dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
In [236]: d = df[list('ABC')].eq('Null')

In [246]: pd.DataFrame([[s[s].index[0]+1, s[s].index[-1]+1, 'Null', c] 
                        for c, s in d.items()], 
                       columns=['StartIndex', 'EndIndex', 'Comment', 'ColumnName'])
Out[246]:
   StartIndex  EndIndex Comment ColumnName
0           2         4    Null          A
1           4         4    Null          B
2           3         4    Null          C
```

---

**Option 2**

```
In [225]: df[['A','B','C']].eq('Null').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
                      [x[x].index[0]+1, x[x].index[-1]+1, 'Null', x.name],
                      index=['StartIndex', 'EndIndex', 'Comment', 'ColumnName'])
                    ).T
Out[225]:
  StartIndex EndIndex Comment ColumnName
A          2        4    Null          A
B          4        4    Null          B
C          3        4    Null          C
```

Comment: Zero, Lets say I have empty space instead of NULL in the columns, is there a way to check for it. Also, Is there a way to pass columns instead of manually providing them in both the options as df[['A','B','C']?

Comment: Use `.eq('')` and to apply on all columns use `df.eq()..`

Comment: Zero, I am having the following error, when I tried using the comments. TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Comment: Zero, I tried using .isnull() instead of eq() to check for NULL data which worked, but the results are not iterating over all rows. It only finds the first set of data with NULL values. It would be really helpful if you can help me out to iterate over all rows and get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with dataframe definition, you can do the same by replacing `Null` with `np.NaN`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, None, None, None, 29], 'B': [15, 20, 10, None, 35], 'C': [20, 11, None, None, 40]},
                  index = range(1,6))
vars = df.columns.tolist()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df = df.melt(id_vars=['index'], value_vars=vars, var_name='ColumnName')

df = df[df['value'].isnull()].groupby(['ColumnName'], as_index=False)['index'].agg({'StartIndex': 'first', 'EndIndex': 'last'}).assign(Comment=lambda x: np.NaN)

df

#  ColumnName  EndIndex  StartIndex  Comment
#0          A         4           2      NaN
#1          B         4           4      NaN
#2          C         4           3      NaN
```

Comment: Zipa, Is there a way to pass columns instead of manually providing them as value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C']?

Comment: You can, before resetting index you can put them in a list using `df.columns.tolist()` which you'll put in a variable and then reset the index and pass columns as the previously defined variable.

Comment: Zipa, I tried using the edited code you suggested. It works fine with the data set provided as example here, but when I tried to add more rows for columns - A, B and C. with some more NULL values. Code provides results as start index as when data was first NULL and end index as when data was NULL for the last time. It skips even if data is in between NULL periods. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: @NewCoder It is made to work that way, what output would you expect for the mentioned cases?

Comment: I am expecting results in similar fashion but it should be able to iterate over many rows and columns and be able to provide results with start and end index when there were NULL data in a large dataset. If you want more information, I can edit the question and explain it there if it would help.